# How to separate Ruby inlineC code to multiple files?

Tags: ruby, inline

I would like to move the MATCH macro and bitmap to a separate file since I use these many places, and I would like to avoid repeating code. How may that be done?

```
require 'inline'

# Class to calculate the Levenshtein distance between two
# given strings.
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
class Levenshtein
  BYTES_IN_INT = 4

  def self.distance(s, t)
    return 0        if s == t;
    return t.length if s.length == 0;
    return s.length if t.length == 0;

    v0 = "\0" * (t.length + 1) * BYTES_IN_INT
    v1 = "\0" * (t.length + 1) * BYTES_IN_INT

    l = self.new
    l.distance_C(s, t, s.length, t.length, v0, v1)
  end

  # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> RubyInline C code <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  inline do |builder|
    # Macro for matching nucleotides including ambiguity codes.
    builder.prefix %{
      #define MATCH(A,B) ((bitmap[A] & bitmap[B]) != 0)
    }

    # Bitmap for matching nucleotides including ambiguity codes.
    # For each value bits are set from the left: bit pos 1 for A,
    # bit pos 2 for T, bit pos 3 for C, and bit pos 4 for G.
    builder.prefix %{
      char bitmap[256] = {
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 1,14, 4,11, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0,10, 0, 5,15, 0,
          0, 0, 9,12, 2, 2,13, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 1,14, 4,11, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0,10, 0, 5,15, 0,
          0, 0, 9,12, 2, 2,13, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      };
    }

    builder.prefix %{
      unsigned int min(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c)
      {
          unsigned int m = a;

          if (m > b) m = b;
          if (m > c) m = c;

          return m;
      }
    }

    builder.c %{
      VALUE distance_C(
        VALUE _s,       // string
        VALUE _t,       // string
        VALUE _s_len,   // string length
        VALUE _t_len,   // string length
        VALUE _v0,      // score vector
        VALUE _v1       // score vector
      )
      {
        char         *s     = (char *) StringValuePtr(_s);
        char         *t     = (char *) StringValuePtr(_t);
        unsigned int  s_len = FIX2UINT(_s_len);
        unsigned int  t_len = FIX2UINT(_t_len);
        unsigned int  *v0   = (unsigned int *) StringValuePtr(_v0);
        unsigned int  *v1   = (unsigned int *) StringValuePtr(_v1);

        unsigned int i    = 0;
        unsigned int j    = 0;
        unsigned int cost = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < t_len + 1; i++)
          v0[i] = i;

        for (i = 0; i < s_len; i++)
        {
          v1[0] = i + 1;

          for (j = 0; j < t_len; j++)
          {
            cost = (MATCH(s[i], t[j])) ? 0 : 1;
            v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost);
          }

          for (j = 0; j < t_len + 1; j++)
            v0[j] = v1[j];
        }

        return UINT2NUM(v1[t_len]);
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`builder.prefix` is just a method call, so you could create a Ruby method which called it with your macro and character array, and then add it to any class which wanted to use those C snippets inline. e.g.

```
module MixinCommonC
  def add_match_macro inline_builder
    inline_builder.prefix %{
      #define MATCH(A,B) ((bitmap[A] & bitmap[B]) != 0)
    }
  end
end
```

In your example code you make the following changes to use it:

At the start of the class

```
class Levenshtein
  extend MixinCommonC
```

(It's `extend` and not `include`, because the `inline` method is being called against the class, so can only access class methods inside the block)

Where you currently have the call to `builder.prefix`:

```
add_match_macro( builder )
```

Comment: Hm, I fail at getting it to work: https://gist.github.com/maasha/7b7ed954d52ae391f20c

Comment: My mistake - use `extend` and not `include`, because the `inline` command is being called against the class, so needs class methods. `include` is for mixing in instance methods.